# Tracking colored ball with Opencv Java

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing, hsv, video-tracking

This is my first time working with opencv. I choose it because I had experience coding with JAVA. But I have had some difficulties when trying to solve my coding problems.

1. My first problem:

I want to catch color from a frame so that when I click with my mouse it gives me RGB colors, which I can convert to HSV and send to my "inRange Method" and I can track any color I choose from my frame.
It doesn't work. It gives me colors that have no relation with the color I selected.

2. My second problem:

I want to detect the contour from my object and detect its position or its distance from the camera, but I'm not sure how.

Here is my code:

```
package application;

import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.Event;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.event.EventType;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.Slider;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;

import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.CvType;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.MatOfByte;
import org.opencv.core.MatOfPoint;
import org.opencv.core.Scalar;
import org.opencv.core.Size;
import org.opencv.highgui.Highgui;
import org.opencv.highgui.VideoCapture;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;


public class FxController 
{
    double h=0,s=0,v=0,tolerance=10;
    @FXML 
    private Button start_b;
    @FXML 
    private ImageView currentFrame,currentFrame2;
    @FXML
    private Slider hSlider,sSlider,vSlider;
    @FXML
    private Label hLabel,sLabel,vLabel;

    private Pane rootElement;
    private Timer timer;
    private VideoCapture capture = new VideoCapture();
    private EventHandler handler;
    private  int red,green,bleu;
    private double alpha ;

    //private float hsb[];
     @FXML 
    protected void startCamera(ActionEvent event)
    {
        if(this.rootElement!=null)//savoir wache main class est accessible 
        {
            final ImageView frameView = currentFrame;//prendre l'objet ImageView pour montre le streaming
            final ImageView frameView2 = currentFrame2;
            /*handler = new EventHandler(){//clic dial la souris wesst l'image


                @Override
                public void handle(Event e) {
                    System.out.println("YOOOOO"+e.getEventType());


                }
            };*/
            frameView.setOnMouseClicked(Event->{Mat m= new Mat();
                                                    byte[] pixel=new byte[4];
                                                    //int [] rgb = new int[3];
                                                    float[] hsv = new float[3];
                                                    //Imgproc.cvtColor(grabMat(0),m,CvType.CV_8UC1);
                                                    grabMat(0).convertTo(m, CvType.CV_8UC3);
                                                    m.get((int)Event.getX(),(int)Event.getY(),pixel);
                                                    /*alpha=(pixel[0] >> 24) & 0xff;
                                                    red=(pixel[1] >> 16) & 0xff;
                                                    green=(pixel[2] >> 8) & 0xff;
                                                    bleu=(pixel[3]) & 0xff;*/
                                                    alpha=pixel[0] & 0xff;
                                                    red=pixel[1] & 0xff;
                                                    green=pixel[2] & 0xff;//fuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuck 
                                                    bleu=pixel[3] & 0xff;
                                                    hsv=java.awt.Color.RGBtoHSB(red,green,bleu, null);
                                                    System.out.println("alpha= "+alpha+"---red= "+red+"---bleu= "+bleu+"---green= "+green);
                                                    h= hsv[0];
                                                    s=hsv[1];
                                                    v=hsv[2];
                                                    System.out.println("h= "+h+"---s= "+s+"---v= "+v);
                                                    //Event.getX();//x du pixel ou la souris berkat
                                                    //Event.getY();
                                                    //BufferedImage.setRGB(Event.getX(),Event.getY(), Color.getRGB());
                                                    });

            if(!this.capture.isOpened())//voir est c que la capture stream est ouverte
            {
                this.capture.open(0);//commence la capture video 
                //prendre le fram chaque 33 ms(30 frames/sec)
                TimerTask FrameGrabber = new TimerTask(){
                    @Override 
                    public void run()
                    {
                        Image tmp = grabFrame(Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2RGBA);//imageRGB
                        //Image tmp2 = grabFrame(Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2HSV);
                        Image tmp3 = newColorDetection(grabMat(Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2HSV));
                        Platform.runLater(new Runnable(){
                            @Override 
                            public void run()
                            {
                                frameView.setImage(tmp);

                                frameView2.setImage(tmp3);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                };
                this.timer = new Timer();
                this.timer.schedule(FrameGrabber,0,33);
                this.start_b.setText("Stop Camera");
                }
            else 
            {
                this.start_b.setText("Start Camera");
                //arrete le timer
                if(this.timer!=null)
                {
                    this.timer.cancel();
                    this.timer = null;
                }
                //realease camera
                this.capture.release();
                //efface le contenaire d'image 
                frameView.setImage(null);
                frameView2.setImage(null);
            }

        }
    }



    private Image grabFrame(int img)
    {
        Image imageToShow =null;//init
        Mat frame = new Mat();// cree une matrice
        //checker si la capture est ouverte
        if(this.capture.isOpened())
        {
            try{
                this.capture.read(frame);//lire le frame courant
                //test si le frame est vide
                if(!frame.empty())
                {
                    //convertire l'image au gris
                    Imgproc.cvtColor(frame, frame,img);
                    //convertir la Mat (objet) a Image (javaFx)
                    imageToShow = mat2Image(frame);
                }
            }catch(Exception e){System.err.println("ERROR: "+e.getMessage());}
        }
        return imageToShow;

    }
    private Mat grabMat(int img)
    {
        Image imageToShow =null;//init
        Mat frame = new Mat();// cree une matrice
        //checker si la capture est ouverte
        if(this.capture.isOpened())
        {
            try{
                this.capture.read(frame);//lire le frame courant
                //test si le frame est vide
                if(!frame.empty())
                {
                    //convertire l'image au gris
                    Imgproc.cvtColor(frame, frame,img);
                    //convertir la Mat (objet) a Image (javaFx)

                }
            }catch(Exception e){System.err.println("ERROR: "+e.getMessage());}
        }

        return frame;

    }


    private Image matToThresHolded(Mat frame)
    {   Image thresHoldedImg =null;
        Mat dFrame = new Mat();
        Imgproc.threshold(frame, dFrame, 127, 255,Imgproc.THRESH_TOZERO);
        thresHoldedImg=mat2Image(dFrame);
        return thresHoldedImg;
    }
    private Image mat2Image (Mat frame)
    {   //cree un buffer temporaire
        MatOfByte buffer = new MatOfByte();
        //encode le frame dans le buffer
        Highgui.imencode(".png",frame, buffer);
        //construire et retourne une image cree depuis l'image encode dans le buffer
        return new Image(new ByteArrayInputStream(buffer.toArray()));

    }
    public void setRootElement(Pane root)
    {
        this.rootElement = root;
    }
    public Image colorDetection(Mat hsvImage)
    {
        Image imageToShow=null;
        Mat threshedImg =new Mat();
        //Scalar hsvMin=new Scalar(106,60,90,0);//red
        //Scalar hsvMax=new Scalar(124,255,255,0);//red
        Scalar hsvMin=new Scalar(100,150,100);//bleu
        Scalar hsvMax=new Scalar(140,255,255);//bleu
    Core.inRange(hsvImage,hsvMin, hsvMax, threshedImg);
    imageToShow = mat2Image(threshedImg);
     return imageToShow;
    }
    public  Image newColorDetection(Mat hsv)
    {

        Image imageToShow=null;
        Mat threshedImg =new Mat(); 
        Mat threshedImg2 =new Mat();    
        Scalar hsvMin = new Scalar(0, 50, 50, 0);//red
        Scalar hsvMax = new Scalar(6, 255, 255, 0);//red
        Scalar hsvMin2 = new Scalar(175, 50, 50, 0);//red
        Scalar hsvMax2 = new Scalar(179, 255, 255, 0);//red
        //Scalar hsvMin=new Scalar(100,150,100);//bleu
        //Scalar hsvMax=new Scalar(140,255,255);//bleu
        //Scalar hsvMin=new Scalar(h-tolerance-1, s-tolerance, 0);//default
        //Scalar hsvMax=new Scalar(h+tolerance-1, s+tolerance,255);//default
     Core.inRange(hsv,hsvMin,hsvMax,threshedImg);
     Core.inRange(hsv, hsvMin2, hsvMax2, threshedImg2);
     Core.bitwise_or(threshedImg, threshedImg2, threshedImg);
    // dilate et erosion pour renforce l'image et supprime les pixels lmcheyrin 
    Mat dilate = Imgproc.getStructuringElement(Imgproc.MORPH_DILATE, new Size(3, 3));
        Imgproc.dilate(threshedImg, threshedImg, dilate);//dilate   
    Mat erode = Imgproc.getStructuringElement(Imgproc.MORPH_ERODE, new Size(3, 3));
        Imgproc.erode(threshedImg, threshedImg, erode);
        List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();    
        Imgproc.findContours(threshedImg, contours, new Mat(), Imgproc.RETR_LIST,Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
        imageToShow = mat2Image(threshedImg);
     return imageToShow;

    }
}
```

My main

```
package application;

import org.opencv.core.Core;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;

public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("FristProjectFX.fxml"));
            BorderPane root = (BorderPane)loader.load();
            Scene scene = new Scene(root);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
            primaryStage.setTitle("JavaFx YO!");
            primaryStage.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();//show GUI
            FxController controller = loader.getController();
            controller.setRootElement(root);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

here's what I got
[image]

like what you see in the picture below when I click on the red zone I don't get red color CODE and even for other color .

and My expectation is

[image]

like what you see on the picture I can catch the ball and the distance!

Comment: Please try to chop up your question to match the problem descriptions to the relevant parts of your source and consider providing some images (reality vs expectation) to help us understand your problem more easily

Comment: I can't put Image ,they said that I need 10 in my reputation to do it

Comment: @BassimRaji, that should do

Comment: I don't know if it's clear now ?

Comment: First of all, use OpenCV `cvtColor()` to convert the image to HSV right in the `onMouseClick()` lambda and then use the pixel coordinates to obtain your HSV. Second, you should probably threshold only on the Hue component of the HSV image, which reduces to a grayscale-like thresholding (except its 0-180 instead of 0-255)

Comment: @mirosval so I did what you said but the probleme is the result value of hsv is negative 
it gives me something like that : h= 123.0---s= -81.0---v= 16.0

Comment: Then there must be something wrong with the way you convert it. See [this](http://forum.openframeworks.cc/t/problems-with-opencv-convert-rgb-to-hsv/368) for  more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the soltuion of the first problem

```java
frameView.setOnMouseClicked(Event->{
    Mat m= new Mat();
    double[] pixel=new double[3];
    float[] hsv = new float[3];
    grabMat(0).convertTo(m, CvType.CV_8U);
    Imgproc.cvtColor(m, m, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2RGB, 3);
    pixel=m.get((int)Event.getX(),(int)Event.getY());
    red=pixel[0];
    green=pixel[1];
    bleu=pixel[2];
    System.out.println("X= "+Event.getX()+"Y="+Event.getY()+"---red= "+red+"---bleu= "+bleu+"---green= "+green);
    hsv=java.awt.Color.RGBtoHSB((int)red,(int)green,(int)bleu, null);
    h= hsv[0];
    s=hsv[1];
    v=hsv[2];
    System.out.println("h= "+h+"---s= "+s+"---v= "+v);                              
});
```